# How to set index NaN (empty cell )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

[image]

```
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
ws = gc.open("Data").worksheet("test3")

df = get_as_dataframe(ws).set_index('A')

# update
df._set_value('Bat', 'B', '11')
df._set_value('Bat', 'C', '12')
df._set_value('Bat', 'D', '13')
df.loc[ str('Fog')] = ''

df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
print(df)
```

output

```
       B    C    D
A                 
Cat    5    6    9
Dog    3    1    7
Bat   11   12   13
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
..   ...  ...  ...
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Fog
```

and I want to be like this  ....have 3 index Cat,Dog,Bat and I want to set NaN cell to new index name Fog after change value in Bat index

```
       B    C    D
A                 
Cat    5    6    9
Dog    3    1    7
Bat   11   12   13
Fog  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
..   ...  ...  ...
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach, I get the datafame without `NaN` index and append 'Fog' to it. Then, I add the `NaN` rows to the above-mentioned dataframe using [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
import io 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creation of an example of dataframe
s_e='''
  A   B    C    D
                 
Cat    5    6    9
Dog    3    1    7
Bat   11   12   13
'''
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s_e), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

df=df.set_index('A')
df._set_value('Bat', 'B', '11')
df._set_value('Bat', 'C', '12')
df._set_value('Bat', 'D', '13')
for i in range(5):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns, index=[np.nan])
    df=df.append(df1)
df=df.rename_axis("A")
print(df)


#Adding the row 'Fog'
df1=df[~df.index.isna()].append(pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns, index=['Fog']))
df=df1.append(df[df.index.isna()])
df=df.rename_axis("A")


print(df)
```

Output:

```
df:
        B     C     D
A                    
Cat   5.0   6.0   9.0
Dog   3.0   1.0   7.0
Bat  11.0  12.0  13.0
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

newdf:
        B     C     D
A                    
Cat   5.0   6.0   9.0
Dog   3.0   1.0   7.0
Bat  11.0  12.0  13.0
Fog   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```